# ¿Cómo evitar contenido duplicado mediante las propiedades alternate, canonical, www y sitemap?

Tags: html, xml, seo, google-search-console

He leido una tras otras y tras otras las ayuda de Google sobre [sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=es) y [url canónicas](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) y sigo sin poder entender.

Google menciona que debemos seleccionar ***el uso de dominio preferido*** con `wwww` o sin `www` con esta configuración se define qué host, ya incluya "www" o no, debería considerarse como host canónico al indexar tu sitio web.

Para la configuración del dominio preferido en **Webmasters** Search Console, tuve que verificar el dominio en las dos formas con `www` y sin `www`

- `http://wwww.example.com/`
- `http://example.com/`

> **Nota:** En mi caso mi configuración de dominio preferido es no usar en el dominio las `www` prefiero no usarlas.

Ahora el problema está en evitar el contenido duplicado cuando diferentes **URL** apuntan en realidad a la misma página, típico en la página de inicio::

- www.example.com
- www.example.com/index.php
- example.com
- example.com/index.php

¿Ahora mi pregunta es cómo especificar en el archivo sitemap la url canonical? o como hacerle saber que es el mismo contenido de las **URLs** sin que Google lo vea como contenido duplicado.

> Cabe recalcar que la **URL** canónica principal deseada es el dominio sin `www` `http://example.com/`

Mi archivo **sitemap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
  <lastmod>2017-02-09T06:34:17+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/index.php</loc>
  <lastmod>2017-02-09T06:34:17+00:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Llego tarde, veo que te han explicado bien el tema.

Comment: @OscarGarcia :) Si amigo esta muy bien pero aun no le comprendo porque a pesar de redirigir www.example.com a otro example.com google igual indica que se debe especificar a una url canonical, como es mismo inicio no podria implementar entonces creo que la solución más factible es mediante el **sitemap.xml** lo unico que me falta es enviar a Google el **sitemap.xml** pero debo evitar que estas paginas google las vea como duplicado ya que se basa al mimo inicio www.example.com y example.com como www.example.com/index.php y example.com/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver si te puedo echar una mano:

-Sólo debes tener un dominio, o www.xxxx o xxxx y uno debe redirigir al otro.
En cuanto al problema de varias urls que apuntan a la misma página debes solucionarlo también con redirecciones 301. Como en los inmortales, sólo puede quedar una.

Los redirect te ahorrarán que tengas que gestionar urls canonicas.

-NO sé si estás usando un CMS como wordpress o no. En el sitemap.xml sólo debe haber una url. Entiendo que al tener esas urls tipo index.php es que estás utilizando una solución propietaria.

En esa solución, al generar el sitemap debes encargarte de que sólo se muestre una url. Si no lo consigues, no te preocupes, Google se cabreará al ver que revisa varias urls diferentes y todas le redirigen a la misma (por que has hecho el redirect 301). Esto no es bueno, pero no es un factor que sea muy malo.

Si quieres, echa un vistazo a este artículo que he hecho sobre [contenido duplicado](https://fullanchor.com/contenido-duplicado/) y espero te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Hola @Javier Muy claro pero aun no comprendo muy bien este tema... Yo tengo especificado la **Url canónica** `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />` pero  esto lo genero automatico con **PHP** Es decir las partes header y las etiquetas estan basadas mediantes varibles de php para hacier poder hacer cambio sin tener que editar las paginas individuales... Ahora digo automático porque si yo visito la  **URLs** de esta manera www.example.com la **Url canónica** se genera automaticamente de esta manera `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />`

Comment: Igualmente si yo visito la **Url** de esta manera `example.com`  la **Url canónica** se genera automaticamente de esta manera `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />`

Comment: Buenas, tu solo puedes tener una página o www.example.com o example.com. Por lo que comentas metes bien el canonical. Si prefieres, como me ha parecido entender, el dominio www.example.com, entonces tienes que hacer un redirect de este tipo en el htaccess

Comment: #Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: Puedes ver más información aquí: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/force-www-htaccess

Comment: si amigo ya tengo realizado el redirect de www.example.com a example.com hasta ahí todo claro ahora el problema es que tengo que indicar el archivo **sitemap.xml** Porque por ejemplo aunque ya tengo ya un `redirect` tengo el index.php que es el mismo inicio de la página principal... No tengo que especificar en el archivo **sitemap.xml** las otras páginas www.example.como, www.example.com/index.php, example.com/index.php o se debe incluir igual pero con un **rel alternate**

Comment: Esa es mi duda @Javier

Comment: Buenas, introduce sólo una url en el sitemap, que entiendo debe ser la raíz www.example.com