# Mostrar imágenes según fecha de adición PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<link href="http://ogar.pw/assets/css/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row center">
    <ul>
        <?php
            # Skin directory relative to include/gallery.php (this file)
            $skindir = "../skins/";
            # Skin directory relative to index.html
            $skindirhtml = "./skins/";
            $images = scandir($skindir);
            foreach($images as $curimg) {
                if (strtolower(pathinfo($curimg, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == "png") {
        ?>
        <li class="skin" onclick="$('#myskin').val($(this).find('.title').text());" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="circular" style='background-image: url("<?php echo $skindirhtml.$curimg ?>")'></div>
            <h4 class="title"><?php echo pathinfo($curimg, PATHINFO_FILENAME); ?></h4>
        </li>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Llevo este código, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo para que se muestren en orden de adición de la imagen al directorio?, osea la imagen que más reciente se haya agregado a la carpeta de las imagenes, se mostrara primero.

Comment: A ver si entendí, quieres mostrar de primero las imágenes recientes que han añadido, osea, hacer un *sort* por fecha? qué nombre tienen los archivos? tienen la fecha incluída?

Comment: por ejemplo si añadi al directorio de las imagenes la imagen x.png esa se mostrara primero y asi sucesivamente , no tienen la fecha incluida en ninguna parte , ese es todo el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un rastreo del directorio, obtener la fecha de modificación, convertirla en un formato de fecha que permita ordenación de texto igual que la ordenación temporal y, por último, agregarle el nombre de archivo para evitar duplicidades.

Cuando ordenamos por clave con [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) estamos manteniendo los datos de la matriz, pero alterando el orden dependiendo del valor de la clave. Si queremos hacer el orden inverso basta con cambiarlo por [`krsort()`](http://php.net/krsort).

```
$skindir = "../skins/";
$images_ini = scandir($skindir);
$images = [];
foreach ($images_ini as $image) {
  $clave = date('Y-m-d H:s:i ', filemtime($skindir . $image)) . $image;
  $images[$clave] = $image;
}
ksort($images);
foreach($images as $curimg) {
[...]
```

Ésta es una versión en la que puedes preprocesar la fecha de última modificación en el formato que quieras:

```
$skindir = "../skins/";
$images_ini = scandir($skindir);
$images = [];
foreach ($images_ini as $imagen) {
  $horam = filemtime($skindir . $imagen);
  $clave = date('Y-m-d H:s:i ', $horam) . $imagen;
  $images[$clave] = [
    /* Usa aquí el formato que más te guste de fecha */
    'fecha' => date('d/m/Y', $horam),
    'fecha' => date('d/m/Y', $horam),
    'fecha y hora' => date('d/m/Y H:m:i', $horam),
    'archivo completo' => $skindir . $imagen,
    'imagen' => $imagen,
  ];
}
ksort($images);
foreach($images as $curimg) {
  /* Aquí tienes disponible los datos en forma de matriz asociativa: */
  $curimg['imagen']; /* El nombre del archivo */
  $curimg['fecha']; /* Sólo la fecha de modificación */
  $curimg['fecha y hora']; /* Fecha y hora de modificación */
  /* etc */
[...]
```

Comment: Podrias explicarme mejor ? soy aprendiz en PHP =)

Comment: Perdona, me pillaste editando la explicación :) Básicamente te dejo preparada una matriz llamada `$images` que puedes usarla con un `foreach` de manera similar a la que la usabas con la salida directa de `scandir`, pero con sus datos procesados y ordenados.

Comment: Excelente! gracias, aunque yo buscaba el krsort , me ha servido un montonaso ! muchisimas gracias =)

Comment: Mira mi última edición, he agregado una forma de hacerlo que te permite guardar más información (toda la que quieras) del archivo en la matriz que ordenas.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia :) Me podría ayudar con mi pregunta nadie la ha tomado en cuenta :( ni para calificar como mala [mí pregunta 1](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48538/cómo-evitar-contenido-duplicado-mediante-las-propiedades-alternate-canonical) y mi [segunda pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48529/cómo-especificar-caché-de-navegador-pagespeed-insights) puedes echarle un vistazo a ver si podrías ayudarme.

Comment: Hola @J.Mick, ¡cuánto tiempo! :) Vi tu pregunta, pero no tenía tiempo y la dejé pasar. Cuando tenga un hueco echamos un vistazo a ese `.htaccess`. Un saludo!

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias amigo :) buen día. Saludos.

Answer (score -2):

si quieres ver las imagenes mas nuevas es asi pero las quieres por timpo usa la funcin time() al momento de subice en la DB MYSQL NUEVO CAMPO **TIME**

```
  $pedir = mysql_query("Select * From imagenes ORDER BY imagen");
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($pedir)){
            echo "<img   src='./img/".$data['imagen']. ".png' alt=''>";
        }
     }
```